# How paste in specific cell multiple values in looping using app script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have two sheets, sheetA in which I have data all in one column that I want to pull one by one to the last one, in a specific cell on SheetB. So it would have to be done in a loop together with a sleep from one dice to another, so that it pulls them all to the last one.

I was able to pull the data, but when copying to and specific cell on SheetB, it only pulls the last value from sheetA.

The code I made was like this:

```
function pasteintoasinglecell() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  var ssA = "sheet A"
  var ssB = "Sheet B"
  var list1 = ss.getSheetByName(ssA)
  var list2= ss.getSheetByName(ssB)

  var list1data = list1.getDataRange().getValues();


  for (i=0;i<list1data.length;i++){
    
    
    list2.getRange(1,1).setValue(list1data[i][0])


  }

}
```

My goal with the script is to make a system that changes the references of a specific cell with the loop in this case A1 pulling the value of column A from worksheet A, so that later I forward an email to the person pulled with such information, this being the objective/purpose of going through column A, pulling all matches found. I need to sleep from one reference to another because it needs time for the INDEX and CORRESP to load, for this new correspondence that has changed and forward the email and then go to the next reference and so on until the last value.

Note: I already have the email forwarding system.

Here is the basis in Google Sheets of how I organized it:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YjeW3A_Sg_HHrb1XVypieAcpsA5XSz-F433Hte5dLkE/edit?usp=sharing

I'm new to using App Script, thanks for taking some of your time to my question.

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. You said “it only pulls the last value from sheetA.” That’s not correct. The loop is pulling ALL the values from Column A of Sheet A. BUT, since you are pasting the values into cell A1 of Sheet B, when the script ends the value in cell A1 will be the last value copied by the loop = the last value in Column A of Sheet A. Your question doesn’t explain your goal/purpose in looping through Sheet A. Would you please edit your question to explain this, then perhaps we can assist with helping you develop  your script.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. Done, I hope this makes it easier.

Comment: We are no further advanced. You are doling out tidbits rather than giving us the complete scenario - we can't work this way. In any event, the "need to sleep" suggests a flawed scripting strategy-why use `INDEX` when the name, email address and daily values are all on the same line in SheetA; why "copy/paste" when you can just assign values to variables and include them in `sendEmail()` (for example). And, `CORRESP`, what is that?